# Other frameworks with compile time/ runtime "mixins" feature like Spring Roo for Java

Tags: java, aop, spring-roo, code-injection, mixins

I am wondering there is any framework which automatically injects methods into Java class similar to Spring Roo's "mixins".

For Example in Spring roo we defile class as follows:

```
    @RooEntity public class Hello {
        private String world;
    }
```

And the Roo framework generates all the necessary methods at compile time as follows:

```
 public class Hello {
  private String world {..}
  public String getWorld() {..}
  public void setWorld(String world) {..}
  public Long getId() {..}
  public void setId(Long id) {..}
  public Integer getVersion() {..}
  public void setVersion(Integer version) {..}
  public String toString() {..}
  public void persist() {..}
  public void remove() {..}
  public void flush() {..}
  public static Long countHellos() {..}
  public static Hello findHello(Long id) {..}
  public static List findAllHellos() {..}
  public static List findHelloEntries(int start, int finish) {..}
  // there are even more methods
 }
```

I do not want to use Spring Roo but want some other framework that dose just this.

Thanks in advance.

Abhishek

Comment: After much search I found Project Lombok which dose similar thing http://projectlombok.org/

Answer (score 1):

**Try Sculptor:**
Overview: "sites.google.com/site/fornaxsculptor/"
Real stuff: http://fornax.itemis.de/confluence/display/fornax/Sculptor+(CSC)

Many tutorials are available which you can follow and learn as you go.

It does much more than entity generation. It can build you full DDD layer in seconds. You can build also GUI with JSF, Smartclient and Eclipse Rich GUI.

We are using it for production projects for years. Success story on Sculptor blog. If you have any questions, you are welcome on "groups.google.com/group/fornax-platform/"

Sorry for short links, can't submit more than one because of "spam prevention" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo's mixin is based on AspectJ [inter-type declarations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html). At least Roo only generates .aj files, and AspectJ woves that into the "normal" java files. -- So if you do not find any framework that does what you want, then build your own Code generator, for example based on [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).

By the way: I do not know any other than Roo that does it in this way, but I remember (75% sure) that some of Roos ideas based on an other Frameworks. (But I can't find the article where I have read that.)